# Regex for a particular pattern

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract a string that looks something like this(below) using java regex.

```
Automotive Vehicles  (154949)

Cars  (91364)

Auto Parts & Accessories  (29987)

Motorcycles & Scooters  (11648)
```

I have tried the following below:

```
for (Element link : links) {
    String cat = link.text();
    String pattern = "(\\w+\\w+?\\s?.?\\w+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(cat);
    while (m.find( )) {
        System.out.println("Category: "+m.group(0));         
    } 
}
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Elaborate on your question please. What is the input, what output you are expecting and your attempt at the problem.

Comment: Really you need to first, show a self attempt (as is requested in the majority of SO questions,) and also, can you possibly try to be rephrase your question, as it appears a bit confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Extract the text and the number with a vim regex

```
\(.*\)(\(\d*\))
```

Group 1 is the text,  Group 2 is the number

So.. it's been a while since I've done RegExs in Java but I think its:

```
(.*)\((\d+)\)
```

Comment: This is perfect @Shaun thanks :). Only problem I'm faced with now is that its extracting the wrong values in brackets. I am "scraping" a site using JSoup with the categories as mentioned above but i cant seem to get the values now. Thanks so much, finding the strings(text) works perfect :)